# How to clear dropdown options value?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently i am facing an unknown problems. I am using customized dropdown list in MVC4 and populating data by ajax. It is working fine but problem is, it is not clearing data after successfully sending data to the controller. 
Here i tried the example..

```
<select data-placeholder="Select a Brand..." style="width:254px;" name="brand" id="brand">
     <option value=""></option>
</select>

$("#brand").select2({
     width: 254
});
```

For clearing drop down list i have tried like this..

```
$("#brand").val("");
```

I have search many example refreshing data in drop down list but i failed. Please help me to solve the problem.
Here i have shared my long code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#brand").select2({
                width: 254
            });
            $.get('/Settings/Brands/', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, c) {
                    $('#brand').append('<option value="' + c.id + '">' + c.name + '</option>');
                });
            });


            $('#btnAdd').live("click", function () {
                if (confirm("Do you want to Save?") == true) {
                    $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        async: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Settings/ItemAdd/",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: adata,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.msg);
                            $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert(data.msg);
                            $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }
                    });
                }
                $("#itemname").val("");
                $("#batchNo").val("");
                $("#desp").val("");

                $("#brand").find("option").val("");
               $("#ctg").val("");
                $("#supplier").val("");
                $("#unittype").val("");
                $("#qty").val("");
                $("#bprice").val("");
                $("#sprice").val("");
                $("#Edate").val("");
                $("#qlimit").val("");
                $("#vat").val("");
                $("#icode").val("");
            });





        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all options or empty values from options?

Comment: It should be reset as it was before selected.

Comment: Can you please post what you see when you do `("#brand").empty();` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("#brand").empty();
```

More info about jQuery's empty function:
https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mjc7302v/

Comment: The code you showed us above doesn't contain <script> tags. Do you have the javascript between the <script> tags in your live code?

Answer (score 1):

Like all jquery plugin for select controls, the plugin hides the original `<select>` tag and replaces it with its own html. Changing properties of the original select has no impact. Instead your need to use he methods of the plugin.

Although you question asks *How to clear dropdown options value*, from the comments I assume you mean reset it to the default `null` option, in which case it would be

```
$("#brand").select2("val", "");
```

Side notes:

1. Its not clear why you would load the values after the page is loaded
   using an ajax call. You could simply strongly bind it to your model
   using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Brand, model.BrandList, "Select a Brand...")` where you view model contains `public SelectList
   BrandList { get; set; }` (or use a `ViewBag` property for
   `BrandList`) and avoid the unnecessary ajax call.
2. `.live` has been depreciated. Use `.on` instead (although in your
   case your not using event delegation so its simply
   `$('#btnAdd').click(function() { ..`)
3. Use `url: '@Url.Action("ItemAdd", "Settings")',`, not `url: "/Settings/ItemAdd/",` so your url are always correctly generated
4. You can remove all your code for resetting individual controls (e.g.
   `$("#itemname").val("");` etc.) with `$('form').get(0).reset();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#brand").empty();
```

See the jQuery API docs for the [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method.

Comment: It's helpful to add a few words of explanation along with code samples :)